# PFD_MAIN_PLANE and Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I get an error when compiling my project in Delphi RAD Embarcadero FMX:
Undeclared Identifier PFD_MAIN_PLANE . It seems that the function wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB that uses this attribute is not supported in FMX.

Any ideas?

Comment: Winapi.Windows declares PFD_MAIN_PLANE. But your question is not clear enough. Please add additional information about platforms and your code.

Comment: I was afraid that if I proceeded to details I may become unclear.Though I can tell you those: 
I am trying to convert my software from vcl to fmx. This software uses a component which have functions for 3d charts. So in "uses" section it is supposed not to have "Windows"  but FMX.*  & System.*  and some of its libraries need modifications such as this funtion .

Comment: Sounds like yo need to get a 3d charting library for FMX if one exists.  Trying to recompile Windows code to operate with FMX is highly unlikely to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

While you are looking for a FMX replacement for that Windows component, you can use the directive:

```
{$IF DEFINED(MSWINDOWS)}
```

and

```
{$ENDIF}
```

in your uses clause in order for your project to compile in FMX.

Design for FMX is so fundamentally different to VCL though. Sometimes it's better to just roll up your sleeves and start from scratch with a new design that makes sense for mobiles and tablets.